# GPT partitioning on a bios/non-efi motherboard with a SSD

Tags: grub2, partitioning, ssd, gpt

I have a 2 year old Intel DH67CL1 BIOS motherboard(non-efi). I am reading about GPT partitioning and wonder whether it is useful in my case. I have still reservations whether to use GPT and what benefits it offers or continue with MBR. since I read about GPT issues on BIOS: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html

1. I have a 180GB Intel 330 series SSD on to which I propose to install Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04.1. I plan to use a recent gparted live cd for partitioning. I may, later install Windows 7(not sure).
2. Since, only BIOS is available how do I boot Linux with grub2(assuming it as the default bootloader).
3. Does a bios_boot partition is needed? (bios_grub)
4. How to verify SSD partitions are aligned? I read, you have to make a 2mb free space before making partitions and then resize it to 1mb free space preceding in [gparted for proper alignment](http://lifehacker.com/5837769/make-sure-your-partitions-are-correctly-aligned-for-optimal-solid-state-drive-performance). is this still valid?
5. Do we need to keep free, unpartitioned space(for 180GB 7% is 13-14GB unpartitioned space) for "over provisioning"
6. tmpfs for logs and other frequently written files? I have only 4GB ram and will I have to keep the firefox, chrome files on RAM?

Answer (score 0):

On a sub-2TiB disk, the advantages of GPT are modest, but real. The `gdisk` documentation site you referenced includes information on those advantages.

If your motherboard is really only two years old, it almost certainly *does* use EFI. EFI became nearly universal in mid-2011. In fact, many Intel boards used EFIs well before then. Many of these implementations have user interfaces that look just like older BIOSes, though. I've got an Intel motherboard that's got just one EFI option buried somewhere in its menus, so it's easy to overlook. When enabled, the computer boots in EFI mode; when disabled (the default), it uses its Compatibility Support Module (CSM) to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

If you boot from GPT in BIOS mode with GRUB 2, a BIOS Boot Partition (signified by a `bios_grub` flag in `parted` and related tools) is strongly recommended, although there are ways to boot without it. A BIOS Boot Partition is *not* required when booting in EFI mode, or with boot loaders other than GRUB 2.

When booting in EFI mode, an EFI System Partition (ESP), identified in `parted` by a `boot` flag, is required. (Note that a GPT disk's `boot` flag is entirely unrelated to the `boot` flag on an MBR disk.) Note that a disk can contain both a BIOS Boot Partition and an ESP. Setting up the disk in this way can enable you to switch boot modes relatively easily, so if you're not sure what you want to use, preparing the disk this way makes sense.

SSD partition alignment is a bit tricky. Many SSDs are happy with the same 1MiB (2048-sector) alignment that's the default for most modern partitioning programs. Others require something higher, like 1.5MiB or 2MiB. You'll need to research your specific disk to be 100% sure of what's required.